# How to change the background color of child control xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a usercontrol which contains an ellipse inside the Canvas. I am using this control in another window and when i set the background color, i want to change only the background of ellipse.How to change the ellipse(child) background without changing canvas(parent) background color?

Comment: i have one more control in canvas. <Viewbox><Canvas><Ellipse></Ellipse><Othercontrol></Othercontrol></Canvas></ViewBox>. how to change the ellipse background without changing canvas backcolor when i set the background color in xaml. Background="Red"

Comment: You could put all of it in a ContentControl style template and Template Bind the Fill of the Ellipse to the Template so when you use it, it would just be a one line where you would just set the property wherever you use it. This also eliminates repetitive code.

Comment: hold on.  Why doesn't <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red"/> work?  (I added some sizes for testing).

Comment: I just started learning this. I created a user control and used it in a wpf window. when i set the backround color, it changes the color of canvas, i want to change only the ellipse background. <myUserCntrl:controName Background="Red">. the canvas background should not change.

Comment: @sous2817, it'll work. but i used ellipse and othercontol to create a usercontrol. i use this usercontrol in a window and i want to change the background of the ellipse from that window. like i said in previous comment

Comment: you need to use the proprietie: Fill

Answer (score 3):

**1. Add a `DependencyProperty` to the code-behind of your `MyUserControl`.**

Note the 3rd parameter of the `Register` method is whatever the `Type` name is of your `UserControl`

```
    public Brush EllipseFill
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(EllipseFillProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EllipseFillProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EllipseFillProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EllipseFill", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

**2. Add a reference to the xaml file of both the main `Window` and the `UserControl` for the namespace where `MyUserControl` is defined :**

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

**3. Bind the `Fill` property of your `Ellipse` to the dependency property that was defined on `MyUserControl`.**

Note the use of `MyUserControl` in `AncestorType` parameter of the `RelativeSource` binding.

```
<Viewbox>
    <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
        <Ellipse Width="50"
                    Height="20"
                    Canvas.Top="50"
                    Canvas.Left="50"
                    Fill="{Binding Path=EllipseFill, 
                           RelativeSource= {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                           AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}}"
                    />
        <Rectangle Width="20"
                    Height="40"
                    Canvas.Top="10"
                    Canvas.Left="10"
                    Fill="Blue"
                    />
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

**4. Set the `EllipseFill` property on `MyUserControl` in the main `Window`**

```
<local:MyUserControl EllipseFill="Red"/>
```

Comment: thank you @James Durda, It works well, now i have a doubt. I tried clr property and it also works. why we are using dependency property here?

Comment: You are correct, a dependency property isn't required for explicitly setting the EllipseFill property in xaml. It is required if you wish to bind the property like this: `<local:MyUserControl EllipseFill="{Binding FillColor}"/>`